# Custom Navigation with Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I’m working on an application for Android and iOS, which requires a certain flexibility for one or two views. That’s why we created & implemented a service that translated a basic list of objects into a user interface for both iOS & Android. But now that Xamarin.Forms is released, we decided to replace our service by the one Xamarin provides. I did succeed in creating the views with Xamarin.Forms, resulting in better looking & smoother running pages. But my problem lies in the navigation of it. Here is a little drawing on what I would like to achieve:

[image]

I would like my app to start an activity that starts with a custom fragment. **After clicking a button on this fragment, I would like the page I created with the Xamarin.Forms api to be added to my current navigation stack!** Once the user is finished with the Xamarin.Forms page, it navigates to a second custom fragment, all that without breaking the navigation cycle. Does anybody have an idea on how I can achieve this?

*For the iOS developpers: replace Activity with NavigationController & Fragment with ViewController*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [CarouselPage](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17381/carouselpage-or-tabbedpage-within-a-page-or-actually-within-a-grid-row) for Xamarin.Forms' own approach. It doesn't look like that's what you need but you can also look at its source code and maybe make a custom renderer yourself.

You may also want to take a look at [MVVM](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross)

As for the easier/hackier way you'd want to make a button on each page and when the button is tapped execute `Navigation.PushModalAsync(nextPage)` - there won't be a "< Back" button any more, you may need to implement that yourself if you need it.

Comment: Thx for taking the time to answer. I actually have the solution for iOS, because the way you initialize a page in iOS, it returns a UIViewModel that i can add to my navigationcontroller. ( App.GetMainPage().CreateViewController(); ) I was wondering if there was something like this in android, that returns a fragment/activity that i can start to work with.

Comment: @Chris making platform-specific solutions when there are cross-platform ones? I fail to understand the logic

Comment: Because using MvvMCross still forces you to design the user interface, and connect the bindings manually. Xamarin.Form doesn't. We still want to be able to design complex user interfaces for each platform seperatly, but one or two views require a certain flexebility, that should be shared by both platforms ( so if there is ever a change in the page, i can do it for both at the same time with little effort ). Most of our data is seperated verry well, so i don't see the benefits of losing weeks because i have to rewrite it in mvvmcross ( wich is also poorly documented ).

Comment: @Chris and you can achieve the same with PushModalAsync - a much simpler and cross-platform approach... but oh well...

Answer (score 2):

If by your meaning of '**current navigation stack**' is for using the native **Navigation** of each platform, then remember that you don't have to use **Xamarin.Forms**' *Navigation Model* and functions such like **PushAsync**.

If you prefer to do **Navigation** with code specific to each platform then you can do this the same as normal.  Just create your *stub* pages in each *platform specific* project and set the **Xamarin.Forms** content for each page from the *shared project*.

From each *platform specific* *stub* page (*Activity* / *UIView* / *PhoneApplicationPage*) you could then execute an Action<> call setting on the *shared* **Xamarin.Forms** page to help with the navigation, or alternatively, hook into a *custom-event* that is raised from the Xamarin.Forms** page back to the *platform specific* *stub* page to allow you to do navigation from there.

Like *Sten* mentioned there won't be any 'Back' button so you will most likely have to do that yourself.

Comment: Thank you, i'll try it out and let you know how it went :)